# C++ Identifier 'X' is undefined, yet 'X' is defined

Tags: c++

I'm trying to model a pendulum in C++, I want the function which calculates the RHS of the ODE to be private and return a struct containing the pendulums velocity and angle which will be public.

It's good practive in the header file to define all the private members and functions and then the public ones, however if I define my private function which returns a struct before the struct I get the error above.

```
class Pendulum{     
    private:
    double _angle;
    double _length;
    double _velocity;
    double _gravity;

    PendulumData rhs(Pendulum pendulum, double dt); // ERR: identifier PendulumData is undefined 
    
    public:
    Pendulum(); // defaut constructor
    Pendulum(double angle, double length, double velocity, double gravity); // modified constructor

    struct PendulumData {
        double velocity;
        double angle;
    }; // PendulumData definition
    // More definitions...
};
```

I'm not too familiar with nested structs and how they work but is there a way to fix this without defining the rhs functions after the struct? As to not have the definitions go private, public, private, public?

Comment: No. C++ requires all symbols to be defined before usage. You could declare `PendulumData` without body (a.k.a. forward declaration) earlier and complete that struct/class later. However `rhs` would have to return a pointer to `PendulumData`. If you want to return `PendulumData` then there's no way around it: complete definition has to be known beforehand.

Comment: And for reference, there is absolutely no problem with defining public members/methods/nested types before private ones. Just put things in the order they need to be in.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, I always write subclass definitions first, just to make sure that I shall be allowed to use them without problem later.

Comment: @freakish I was afraid this would be the case, I've been watching some pluralsight tutorials and they keep saying it's bad practise to alternate between private and public function definitions

Comment: it is bad practice to use youtube videos to spread cargo cult :P. There is absolutely nothing wrong with mixing members of different access. Just keep in mind readability, and consider that they are initialized in the order they appear in the class, hence sometimes it is necessary to rearrange them

Comment: @JCater "bad practice" is meaningful only when you have a choice in that matter. In that case you don't have a choice. Unless you completely redesign your entire code, e.g. `PendulumData` outside of `Pendulum`. Which actually is not a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Define the nested class before you use it. You can mix blocks of `private`,`public` and `protected` as you wish:

```
class Pendulum{     
    private:
        // ....      
    public:
        Pendulum(); // defaut constructor
        Pendulum(double angle, double length, double velocity, double gravity);
        struct PendulumData {
            double velocity;
            double angle;
        };
    private:
        PendulumData rhs(Pendulum pendulum, double dt);   
};
```

Answer (score -1):

You should mention that the pendulum data is a struct, its external doesn't understand what it is. it works with this change. You can also resolve this error by the code that largest_prime_is_463035818 threw. It is entirely up to your design.

```
struct PendulumData rhs(Pendulum pendulum, double dt);
```